# Upload to multiple directories

Tags: php, mysql

In my application I want to save same file in two different directories. In my www folder I have two folders call folder1 and folder2. I uploaded images to the 'uploads' directory within folder1. I want to move this image to folder called 'uploads' which is located inside folder2.

Here is my code.

```
    $target = "uploads/"; 

$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$target2="folder2/uploads/";

//This gets all the other information from the form 

 $desc=$_POST['desc'];
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
 $loc=$_POST['location'];


 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
 mysql_select_db("selfie") or die(mysql_error()) ; 



 $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo']['name']);
 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO image_upload (description,image,location) VALUES     ('$desc','$pic','$loc')"); 


 //Writes the photo to the server  

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
 copy($target, $target2);
  } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

I used 'copy()'. As a new web developer I don't know it's correct or not. My upload.php located inside the folder1.can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target2)) { //you code
```

or

```
copy($target, $target2.basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

Comment: I tried. But it's not work. I don't know syntax of giving target2 correct or not.

Comment: check the file structure.. The path level should be same for both folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use file copy function

[copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

You are uploading the file for the first time.

So, the file resource is moving from its temporary location.

You need to copy the resource from your first directory.

```
$target2 = "folder2/uploads/". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
copy($target, $target2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have almost 90% right in this code. You just have to add one line(i.e fourth line from below to your code)

```
$target = "uploads/"; 

$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$target2="folder2/uploads/";
$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
```